# Data Annotation & Private members in ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor-pages

What is the best practice to add data annotation validators to private class members without having public set (If there is a way)

```
public class Employee{

//private fields

//constructors

   [Required(ErrorMessage = "Required field")]

   [DataType(DataType.Text, ErrorMessage = "Invalid input for firstname")]

   public string FirstName { get { return this.firstName; } }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In C#, a Property represents a private field with bound Get and/or Set methods. It does all the encapsulation for you, so what you are trying to solve is already done.

The code you wrote:

```
class Employee
{
  public string FirstName { get; set; }
}
```

What the compiler sees:

```
class Employee
{ 
  private string _firstName;

  public string GetFirstName()
  {
    return _firstName;
  }

  public void SetFirstName(string firstName)
  {
    _firstName = firstName;
  }
}
```

Comment: I was told that it's a bad practice to have properties with public Setters (for security matters) So changed my classes to have private fields and constructors to initialize these fields, and finally properties with only Getters to get the fields back after initialization..
But now When I am trying to bind some classes to the view templates, I don't know the best practices to do that without having public Setters..

Comment: It is not bad practice because you are not exposing a public member, you are defining a private member and providing get/set methods to access it. it’s bad practice to have public members/fields, which you can read more about here: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/161303/is-it-bad-practice-to-use-public-fields